# R pulling data for one column(X, is a int) when a column(string) matches a unique string

Tags: r, dplyr

I am pulling data from a sql server and need to manipulate the data tables for future stats analysis. The table i am pulling is 4 variables with 600+ observations. My goal is to find a way to get the values of columns X, Y , Z  when a string in column(name) is matched. I want the list to only be the values of the X, Y , Z with no name column .

code so far:

```
library(dplyr)
library(RMySQL)
my_db <- dbConnect(RMySQL::MySQL(),
  dbname = "schema", #name of schema
  host = "host", #name of host
  user= "root", #name of user. typically root default
  password = "password", # my password, unique to your MySQL Workbench
  port = deafult # it is the default port 
)
users <- dbReadTable(my_db, "schema_DT")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm pretty sure this will do the trick:

```
filtered_data<-users %>% filter(special_column=="my string") %>% select(X,Y,Z)
```

Comment: Unfortunately when the code is run it creates a empty data set.

Comment: never mind it works :). i messed up with a extra space in the name